# how to retrieve password value from the database

Tags: android, sqlite

In this userdetails.java i am creating creating a table by name userdetails and inserting values

```
public class userdetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_userdetails);

Button dbsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    dbsave.setOnClickListener(this);

SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Student.db" , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY        , null          );
try {
    final String UserDetails = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserDetails ("
            + "NAME,"
            + "MOB_NO,"
            + "Q_NO,"
            + "Q_ANS,"
            + "MAIL_ID,"
            + "PASSWD);";
    db.execSQL(UserDetails);

    Toast.makeText(userdetails.this, "table created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(userdetails.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(),          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
   }
    public void onClick(View view){

    SQLiteDatabase db;

     if(view.getId()==R.id.save)
     {

         EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String s1=e1.getText().toString();

         EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


         EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         String s3=e3.getText().toString();


         EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
         String s4=e4.getText().toString();


         EditText e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
         String s5=e5.getText().toString();


         EditText e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
         String s6 =e6.getText().toString();

       // Toast.makeText(Databasedb.this, "table created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String sql =
            "INSERT or replace INTO UserDetails (" +
            "Name, " +
            "Mob_no, " +
            "Q_no, " +
            "Q_ans,"+
            "Mail_id,"+
            "Passwd) " +
            "VALUES('"+s1+"','"+e2+"','"+s6+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"','"+s5+"')" ;       

        db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Student.db" , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY        , null          );

        db.execSQL(sql);




         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(userdetails.this).create();
          //  alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

            alertDialog.setMessage("uservalues are successfully added/updated to the database");

            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(userdetails.this, Login.class);
            userdetails.this.startActivity(intent);

               }
        });
            alertDialog.show();     
     }}
```

}

and here is my login.java file from where i need to access the userdetails table

```
 public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    txt.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code);
    forgot.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override

public void onClick(View view) {

         if(view.getId() == R.id.login) 
         {   

      EditText p1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputpasswd);    
       String s = p1.getText().toString(); 

       Intent intent1= new Intent(this,homepage.class);
       startActivity(intent1);

         }


         else 
             if(view.getId()==R.id.sub)
         {
         Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, userdetails.class);
        startActivity(intent2); 
         }
        else 
         {
             Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Forgotpassword.class);
          startActivity(intent3);   

        }


            }
```

}

please any one help me to retrieve values(from login.java) from the database`and  comapare that value from the user entered value

thanx in advance....

Comment: you're not really going to store unencrypted passwords in the database, are you?

Comment: See http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/ - you should never store passwords as plain text

Comment: i didnt understand what u r saying..??

Comment: as though it worked for me... pls help me to retrieve values from the database..

Comment: @bharathipatil: wen you want to retrieve values from db ?

Comment: in login.java file(in onclick function).... i want retrieve value from the database there and compare with the user entered value...

Comment: You want to store passwords in a local db? What's the use case for this?

Comment: yes... in local database only i wanna store...

Comment: Your login.java code is completely  irrelevant to the actual question. Don't post irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You execute a query of the general form

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?
```

and see whether the count returned is 1 or 0.

- That way it's the *database* that does the comparing.
- Also you don't have to deal with details of the password hashing in your code, as you would if you received and compared yourself.
- Also there is much less data movement.
- Also this procedure means that you can't leak to the user whether his username or his password was incorrect in the event of a failure, which conforms with good security design practice.

Answer (score -1):

To check whether user have entered the proper credentials or not. Use this following code.

```
String username="";
String password=""; 
Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from Users where Username="+username+ " and Password="+password);
if(c.getCount()>0){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succesful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please format this illegibile mess properly so it can be evaluated.